# Proof of rank-nullity via the first isomorphism theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

I was thinking about the proof of the rank-nullity theorem and I thought about proving it as follows. I just wondered whether this proof worked?

**Lemma.** If $V$ is a finite-dimensional $F$-vector space and $U\leq V$, then $V/U$ is finite dimensional.

$\hspace{16.5mm}$ Moreover, we have that $\dim{V/U}=\dim{V}-\dim{U}$.

**Theorem (Rank-Nullity).** If $\alpha:V\to W$ is linear with $V$ finite-dimensional, then
$$\dim{V}=\dim(\text{im }\alpha)+\dim(\ker \alpha)$$

**Proof.** By the first isomorphism theorem we have
$$V/\ker{\alpha} \cong \text{im }{\alpha}.$$
Taking dimensions and applying the lemma we get
$$\dim V - \dim(\ker\alpha)=\dim(\text{im }\alpha)$$
which on rearrangement yields the result. //

Comment: Not only this works, it is more natural from an algebraic point of view. Moreover, it gives a version of the theorem that applies to infinite-dimensional vector spaces as well (i.e. the first isomorphism theorem). I am a fan of this approach.

Comment: Looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: Related to my previous comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/752056/8157

Comment: I notice also that the identity
$$\dim(U+V)=\dim(U)+\dim(V)-\dim(U\cap V)$$
follows from the Second Isomorphism Theorem :)

But that the third isomorphism theorem tells us nothing in terms of dimension!