# rank-nullity theorem clarification

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The rank-nullity theorem says that if linear transformation $T: V\rightarrow W$ then
$$
\\
\dim(Im(T))+\dim(Ker(T))=\dim(V)$$
and equivalently,
$$\\
rank(T) + nullity(T) = \dim(V)
$$
when seeing $T$ as a $m \times n $ matrix.

This makes perfect sense to me whenever $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces of column vectors. However, in terms of vector space of matrices, I got confused easily.

The question is: does rank of $T$ always equal to the dimension of its image? Also how about the relationship between nullity and $\dim (ker(T))$?

Say if $V$ is the vector space of all $2 \times 3$ matrices, and $W$ is the vector space of all $4 \times 1$ matrices, and if T is onto, then what would T look like? (i.e. what are m and n?)

Following the first expression of RNT, it suggests that T should have a corresponding range of 4, and the kernel should have a dimension of 2, but does it mean that $rank(T) = 4$ and $nullity(T) = 2$? If yes, then shouldn't $T$ have definitely 2 columns since $V$ is $2 \times 3$?

Comment: It is really hard to figure out what you are asking. If the first two statements are equivalent, then you have the answer to  your first two questions.

Comment: @copper.hat sorry I think I made a mistake there. rank(T) + nullity(T) = dim(V) but not n... so then T should be a $4 \times 2$ matrix right?

Comment: $T$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}^{\dim V} \to \mathbb{R}^{\dim W}$. If $V$ is the space of $2 \times 3$ matrices, then $\dim V = 6$.

Comment: @copper.hat and that is simply because $ \mathbb{R}^6$ and $\mathbb{R}^4$ is isomorphic to V and W respectively?

Comment: Well, it is because any basis has 6 elements. One basis is $e_i e_j^T$, $i=1,2$, $j=1,2,3$, with the $e_k$ the standard bases in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\mathbb{R}^3$ resp.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the rank-nullity theorem hold for infinite dimensional $V$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752056/does-the-rank-nullity-theorem-hold-for-infinite-dimensional-v)