# If $\operatorname{rank}(T)$ and $\operatorname{null}(T)$ are finite, then $\dim(V)$ is finite

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a vector space and let $T \in \operatorname{End}(V)$. If $\operatorname{rank}(T)$ and $\operatorname{null}(T)$ are finite, prove that $\dim(V)$ is finite.

I cannot use the Rank-Nullity Theorem as it only applies to finite
dimensional vector space and I don't know whether $V$ is finite or infinite dimensional.

Comment: Take basis of $nullspace(T)$ and pick preimages of basis of $image(T)$. Then show that these together generate $V$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use the general fact that

*a vector space always admits a basis*

you can prove the Rank-Nullity theorem without any restriction on the dimension. Indeed

- take a basis $\cal B$ of ${\rm Im}(T)$,
- take a basis $\cal K$ of $\ker(T)$,
- for each $b\in \cal B$, choose a $b^\prime$ such that $T(b^\prime)=b$ and call $\cal B^\prime$ the set of such elements $b^\prime$,
- prove that $\cal K\cup\cal B^\prime$ is a basis of $V$.

Bingo!

Comment: How do i show that $\cal K\cup\cal B^\prime$ is a basis of V

Answer (score 0):

The lemma used to prove this theorem is, on the other hand, always valid (and thus much more important) : if $f:V\to W$ is a linear map and $H$ is a supplement of $\ker(f)$ in $V$ (meaning $V=H\oplus \ker(f)$) then $f$ induces an isomorphism $H\to Im(f)$.

Try to see that the proof carries over to infinite dimension, and use that in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The rank-nullity theorem
$$\dim V = \dim \ker T + \dim im T$$
also holds for infinite-dimensional $V$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752056/does-the-rank-nullity-theorem-hold-for-infinite-dimensional-v). The formula implies the claim.